# Delete duplicates from linked list and save it to another list in C

Tags: c, list, copy, duplicates

I encountered a problem during this task. I'm just take list, check that currently processed element is in it. If is skip it, else add to new list. 
I wrote three function to do this. One that search particular element, next which is checking for element exist in new list, and the last which is get everything together.

I've tried to do this in two ways:

- First checking for occurrence in "old" list, it works, but not at all ( writes to new list in descending order) also I think for particular example it won't work.
- Second checking for occurrence of element in currently created list, but this doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
struct list *search_node(struct list *prt, char *to_search) {
    is_empty();
    short is_found = -1;
    while (prt != NULL && ((is_found = strcmp(prt->word, to_search) != 0))) {
        prt = prt->next;
    }
    if (!is_found)
        return prt;
    else
        return NULL;
}

bool is_on_list(struct list *ptr, char *str) {
    if (search_node(ptr, str) != NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

struct list *without_repetiton(struct list *head) {
    struct list *new_list = NULL;
    struct list **new_el = &new_list;
    struct list *prt1 = head, *check;

    while (prt1 != NULL) {
        //printf("test = %s\n", prt1 -> word);
        check = new_list;
        if (!is_on_list(prt1->next, prt1->word)) { // or (new_list, prt1 -> word) 
            *new_el = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
            memcpy(*new_el, prt1, sizeof(struct list));
            new_el = &((*new_el)->next);
        }
        prt1 = prt1->next;
    }
    return new_list;
}
```

There is the structure of list:

```
struct list {
    char *word;
    struct list *next;
    struct list *prev;
};
```

I have two questions, first why the first approach writes the list in descending order, and second why when I've tried to search occurrence of word in already created list in not work?

IO samples:

When : `is_on_list(prt1->next, prt1->word))`
Fist list: One, One, Two
Second list: Two, One
When : `is_on_list(new_list, prt1->word))`
The first list is the same as second.

Comment: Note that when you copy a node in the list with the `memcpy` function, you don't do a *deep* copy. That is, you only copy the pointer `word`, but not the data it is pointing to. That means you will afterwards have two pointers pointing to the same memory. This might lead to trouble if you later try to modify the string for one list as then both list will have the update. Or when you (possibly) try to free the memory and might do it twice. Also, there's is a simpler way of doing shallow copying of structures like that: `**new_el = *prt1`.

Comment: `((is_found = strcmp(prt -> word, to_search) != 0))` is suspect.

Comment: what is the problem? can you give input and output samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not construct the duplicate list correctly: simplify the code and link the new elements by hand instead of using `memcpy()`:

```
struct list *search_node(struct list *ptr, const char *to_search) {
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp(ptr->word, to_search))
            return ptr;
    }
    return NULL;
}

bool is_on_list(struct list *ptr, const char *str) {
    return search_node(ptr, str) != NULL;
}

struct list *without_repetiton(struct list *head) {
    struct list *new_list = NULL;
    struct list *tail = NULL;

    for (struct list *ptr = head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
        if (!is_on_list(new_list, ptr->word)) {
            struct list *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
            node->next = NULL;
            node->prev = tail;
            node->str = strdup(ptr->word);
            if (tail == NULL) {
                 new_list = tail = node;
            } else {
                 tail->next = node;
                 tail = node;
            }
        }
    }
    return new_list;       
}
```